# The rep gained from accepted answers should be a multiple of the votes on the question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, reputation, accepted-answer

Right now, when your answer is accepted, you [receive +15 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

What if it was changed so that, if your answer is accepted, you receive a multiple of the votes the question has (with a minimum of ~10)?

So for example, if the question had 5 upvotes and your answer was accepted, you would get 5 * 5 = 25 rep. I think this would increase the number of answers on highly voted, therefore good, questions.

Comment: [16k from upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) and 8k upon accept, that'd be nice!

Comment: Also something to think about: What happens with upvotes *after* the answer was accepted?

Comment: The up-vote and accepted answer mechanism isn't broken - and if it were, your question would be incorrectly tagged.

Answer (score 10):

When a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is proposed, I think there should be a compelling justification offered. I always ask myself, "Why would the site be better if this feature were implemented?" Scanning your post, I see the following justification offered:

> I think this would increase the number of answers on highly voted, therefore good, questions.

I actually think that would be *extremely* problematic, probably even to the point of *undesirable*.

**Popular, well-asked questions already receive a lot of attention**. People already answer those questions whenever they can, so they get plenty of answers. And if those answers are any good, they *also* already get plenty of rep from upvotes to their answer. There doesn't seem to be any reason to provide any more incentives to encourage users to answer those questions.

Really, what we need are incentives to get people to answer well-asked **but unpopular** questions. Those that are in less-trafficked tags, or those that concern difficult or otherwise hard-to-solve problems. Unfortunately, that is not this feature request, so I'm going to have to disagree.

Comment: Exactly. Popular questions aren't the ones that need *additional* attention.

Answer (score 5):

Why? There's already a significant gap between "popular" and "niche" questions; are you proposing to make it even greater?

Also, I see a false premise here: "highly voted" correlates much **more closely** with "yay popular topic, me too" than "good post": even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly/3905805#3905805) is an okay post, I fail to see how could it be worth 400+ upvotes.

Comment: The answer to which you link is CW - not an apples-to-apples comparison. That said, I do think you make a valid point regarding this OP's question.

Comment: @IAbstract: Not really - that answer was changed to CW automatically by the system, after my umpteenth edit (see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3905805/revisions)). IIRC, it went up to approx. +250 before it evolved into CW; that is IMNSHO a valid comparison.

Comment: fair enough - 250 is a lot of up-votes for *any* answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, I'm only answering your question if it has at least 10 upvotes!

Comment: Predicting the future fail.